# python--import data from file and autopopulate a dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, file-io, dictionary

I am a python newbie and am trying to accomplish the following.
A text file contains data in a slightly weird format and I was wondering whether there is an easy way to parse it and auto-fill an empty dictionary with the correct keys and values.

The data looks something like this

```
01> A B 2          ##01> denotes the line number, that's all
02> EWMWEM         
03> C D 3
04> EWWMWWST
05> Q R 4
06> WESTMMMWW
```

So each pair of lines describe a full set of instructions for a robot arm. For lines 1-2 is for arm1, 3-4 is for arm 2, and so on. The first line states the location and the second line states the set of instructions (movement, changes in direction, turns, etc.)

What I am looking for is a way to import this text file, parse it properly, and populate a dictionary that will generate automatic keys. Note the file only contains value. This is why I am having a hard time. How do I tell the program to generate armX (where X is the ID from 1 to n) and assign a tuple (or a pair) to it such that the dictionary reads.

```
dict = {'arm1': ('A''B'2, EWMWEM) ...}
```

I am sorry if the newbie-ish vocab is redundant or unclear. Please let me know and I will be happy to clarify.

A commented code that is easy to understand will help me learn the concepts and motivation.

Just to provide some context. The point of the program is to load all the instructions and then execute the methods on the arms. So if you think there is a more elegant way to do it without loading all the instructions, please suggest.

Comment: Are `'A''B'2` and `EWMWEM` strings?

Comment: I supposed he wanted 'AB2' and 'EWMWEM'.

Comment: @sPaz: thanks for asking. It won't matter if 'A' 'B' is 'AB'. However, I need the 2 to be an int.

Comment: there is no datatype like `'AB'2`.  you could do `{'arm1': ('AB',2,EWMWEM)...}`

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like that:

```
mydict = {} # empty dict
buffer = ''
for line in open('myFile'): # open the file, read line by line
    linelist = line.strip().replace(' ', '').split('>') # line 1 would become ['01', 'AB2']
    if len(linelist) > 1: # eliminates empty lines
        number = int(linelist[0])
        if number % 2: # location line
            buffer = linelist[1] # we keep this till we know the instruction
        else:
            mydict['arm%i' % number/2] = (buffer, linelist[1]) # we know the instructions, we write all to the dict
```

Comment: Looks good. Although I thought the line numbers `01>` were there just for the question. Either way, this should be a good start.

Comment: be careful using the word dict as the name of a variable.  `isinstance(dict,dict)` gives an error

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_instructions_dict(instructions_file):
    even_lines = []
    odd_lines = []
    with open(instructions_file) as f:
        i = 1
        for line in f:
            # split the lines into id and command lines
            if i % 2==0:
                # command line
                even_lines.append(line.strip())
            else:
                # id line
                odd_lines.append(line.strip())
            i += 1

    # create tuples of (id, cmd) and zip them with armX ( armX, (id, command) )
    # and combine them into a dict
    result = dict( zip ( tuple("arm%s" % i for i in range(1,len(odd_lines)+1)),
                      tuple(zip(odd_lines,even_lines)) ) )

    return result

>>> print get_instructions_dict('instructions.txt')
{'arm3': ('Q R 4', 'WESTMMMWW'), 'arm1': ('A B 2', 'EWMWEM'), 'arm2': ('C D 3', 'EWWMWWST')}
```

Note `dict` keys are not ordered.  If that matters, use `OrderedDict`

Comment: Can you explain this part?
 
    `result = dict( zip ( tuple("arm%s" % i for i in range(1,len(odd_lines)+1)),
                      tuple(zip(odd_lines,even_lines)) ) )`

Comment: `zip` takes two lists/tuples and creates a tuple with the nth element of each list/tuple (ie, `zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])==[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]`  `dict` takes a list/tuple and turns it into a dict with the first element as the key so `dict([(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)])=={1:4,2:5,3:6}`...so as the comment above it says, the line zips armX with the tuple of (id, cmd) and turns it into a dict

Comment: then try `zip(('a','b','c'),tuple(zip((1,2,3),(4,5,6))))==[('a', (1, 4)), ('b', (2, 5)), ('c', (3, 6))]`...and finally `dict(zip(('a','b','c'),tuple(zip((1,2,3),(4,5,6)))))=={'a': (1, 4), 'b': (2, 5), 'c': (3, 6)}`

Answer (score -1):

```
robot_dict = {}
arm_number = 1
key = None
for line in open('sample.txt'):
   line = line.strip().replace("\n",'')
   if not key:
       location = line
       key = 'arm' + str(arm_number) #setting key for dict
   else:
       instruction = line
       robot_dict[key] = (location,line)
       key = None #reset key
       arm_number = arm_number + 1
```

Comment: if this is a large file, you don't want to load the whole thing in memory, also be careful using `index + 1`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this comment. How large is large? Also, is there a way to avoid it? I'd love to know any elegant solutions. The point of the program is to load all the instructions and then execute the methods on the arms.

Comment: nm, actually i think it's a moot point since we're creating a dict with everything in it.